# Magento 2 REST API: add item to cart with additional info_buyRequest attributes

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Adding a product to a customer's cart via the [REST API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items.html) is easy enough. However, in our case we also want to add additional `info_buyRequest` options. But the documentation isn't really clear on how to add more buy request attributes for such a request.

We tried with

```
{
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "243612",
        "qty": 1.0,
        "quote_id": "23627",
        "product_option": {
            "info_buyRequest": {
                "foo": "foobar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but had no luck with that. Is there any way to do that?

Magento Version: 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "243612",
        "qty": 1.0,
        "quote_id": "23627",
        "product_option": {
              "extension_attributes": {
                "custom_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "foo",
                        "option_value": "bar"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this really will be in `info_buyRequest`?

Comment: I think, you can see it in `quote_item_option` table

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. These custom options will just live under the `options` key _within_ `info_buyRequest`.